# ACRA crash report sending via email

Tags: android, crash-reports, acra

I'm planning to use ACRA to send crash reports. I want to send crash reports via email. My main requirement is to send email to id which is in "mailTo" of @ReportsCrashes annotation. I don't want app user to know anything about ACRA so I'm setting "mode" to SILENT. ACTION_SEND gives client options like Dropbox,email client,gmail etc but I don't want app user to know anything about things happening behind So what I must do for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not send emails directly from ACRA without the user's permission (since it launches their Email app via an intent). Even if you could, I doubt your user's would appreciate it!

If you want immediate emails on bugs, I'd recommend using BugSense which supports this.